# Does RxJS have a way to handle errors that were not caught by subscriber?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, primeng

RxJS allows to subscribe to a source with onNext, onError, onComplete.

I am looking for a way to construct an observable which allow users to handle errors with onError, but if there is error that is unhandled, I can show globally growl (a notification from primeng library).

Is there a nice way to catch unhandled in subscription errors.

**Update1:**
I have noticed that Angular2 has a central ErrorHandler (Module level). The question is to attach it to UI somehow. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ErrorHandler-class.html

Comment: the `.catch` operator maybe?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not subscribe to the `error` event it will bubble. You can wrap your stream with try..catch to catch these to prevent your application from crashing.

```
try {
  Rx.Observable.throw(new Error('not caught')).subscribe();  
}
catch(err) {
  console.log('caught', err);
}
```

Comment: What about errors from asynchronous sources? They will still be unhandled.

Comment: If you have an asynchronous source you need to ensure that you wrap/catch the error in your Rx stream. Otherwise a try..catch will do nothing to help

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this is not exactly what I want. I will update my question.